# How to implement Twitter button the Angular way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, twitter

I'm having issues implementing a humble tweet button on my site using Angular. I've done some research and found some solutions for an AJAX site using jQuery but as far as I can tell using the solution (below) would involve running script outside of a controller, and would therefore be non-Angular and A Bad Thing.

Has anyone solved this problem in an Angular way or have any tips on how to?

Thanks.

Solution for AJAX:

```
//adding button to dom
$('#tweetbutton').append('<a class="twitter-share-button" href="http://twitter.com/share" data-url="http://www.google.nl>Tweet</a>');
//loading widgets
$.getScript('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function(){
//calling method load
twttr.widgets.load();
```

Taken from:
[Cannot update tweet button with Ajax](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/890)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a gist that might help you out: https://gist.github.com/Shoen/6350967

**directive.js**

```
directives.directive('twitter', [
    function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                        twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
                            attr.url,
                            element[0],
                            function(el) {}, {
                                count: 'none',
                                text: attr.text
                            }
                        );
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<a twitter data-text="Your text: {{file.name}}" data-url="http://127.0.0.1:3000/{{file.link}}"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel. I'm going to leave this open for a little while though as the method you've suggested isn't ideal if the data isn't loaded at page load time. Still a good answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I took a page from the a similar Facebook solution and was able to implement this in the following manner.

In your view, use the standard link button syntax:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Here's something cool">Tweet</a>
```

Then in your Controller (or even in your app load) you use the following code to inject the needed JavaScript properly into the page:

```
    // Load twitter sharing button
    (function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs'));
```

This will properly inject the code into the page and allow your Twitter button to work.